# It is Possible to Get Sdcard Media content using Media store method in Android 11+ version

Tags: java, android

I am Designing one Music appin Android 11 version In this I already get the Internal content but I Tried Lot of method for getting Sdcard media content Finally the android website mentioned Like this The MediaProvider module optimizes indexed metadata (audio, video, and images from SD cards and USB devices) and makes that data available to apps through the MediaStore public APIs

So I tried Media store method.

My code is

```
    if(context != null){
        contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Log.d("d", "amp: "+contentResolver);
        Log.d("d", "amp: "+context);
    }
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
    if(contentResolver != null){
        cursor    = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, sortOrder);


    }

    Log.d(AMPS_LOGS, "ampsGetImageFileList: "+cursor);

    if(partialFetch){
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                boolean imageSupported = false;
                long    imageId      = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
                Uri     imageUri     = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageId);
                String  imageName    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                long    dateModified = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED));
                String  imagePath    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH));
                String  imageType    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE));
```

Here uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL); getting Media file from Internal storage only not Sdcard.

Hi tried MediaStore.External_Content_Uri and MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_Primary

How to get Sdcard media content

My Media Files are in Micro sdcard. It is not Listed in Cursor and MediaStore.Volume External getting Internal media content not getting Micro sdcard content.

Please tell How to get Micro sdcard media content Using Media store method

My micro sdcard file path is /mnt/media_rw/D26C-1EEF How to get this Directory in Media store method

Comment: Your code is a mess and you dont have to write that uri twice. Better do it once correct in the code.

Comment: What do you mean with Sdcard? A removable micro-sd card? Edit your post with good info.

Comment: Tell at least one full path of a file on the micro-sd card that is not listed by the cursor. Write all in your post. Not in a comment. Write a good post.

Comment: @blackapps Hi Explain my micro sdcard file path in post

Comment: You did not tell full path of a file on the card. And the path to the card you mentioned is not usable and irrelevant. Not even a file name you mentioned.

Comment: `Your code is a mess and you dont have to write that uri twice. Better do it once correct in the code.` My god.  why dont you correct your post??

Comment: If you not understand my code means Please answer for this question : In android with the help Media store method we can get the sdcard media content or not ?

Comment: I give it up too.